# Convert max-width to mobile first

Tags: css, responsive, gatsby, styled-components

I have downloaded a excellent tutorial with Gatsby and styled components. This tutorial has a desktop-first approach.

I am trying to convert from desktop-first to mobile first, the desktop-first version is working as it's supposed to, but my conversion to mobile-first does not work.

This is the Navbar.jsx file; this file didn't need to be altered, I believe.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Burger from './Burger';

const Nav = styled.nav`
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .logo {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
`

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <Nav>
      <div className="logo">
        Nav Bar
      </div>
      <Burger />
    </Nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

This the original Burger.jsx with desktop-first, this file is hidden for desktop and imports the actual menu block

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import RightNav from './RightNav'

const StyledBurger = styled.div`
      width: 2rem;
      height: 2rem;
      position: fixed;
      top: 15px;
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 20;
      display: none;
    
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
      } 
    
      div {
        width: 2rem;
        height: 0.25rem;
        background-color: ${({ open }) => (open ? '#ccc' : '#333')};
        border-radius: 10px;
        transform-origin: 1px;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
    
        &:nth-child(1) {
          transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)')};
        }
    
        &:nth-child(2) {
          transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'translateX(100%)' : 'translateX(0)')};
          opacity: ${({ open }) => (open ? 0 : 1)};
        }
    
        &:nth-child(3) {
          transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'rotate(-45deg)' : 'rotate(0)')};
        }
      }
    `
    
    const Burger = () => {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    
      return (
        <>
          <StyledBurger open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            <div />
            <div />
            <div />
          </StyledBurger>
          <RightNav open={open} />
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default Burger
```

This is my attempt to convert it to mobile-first with min-width, the original code is in comment block:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import RightNav from './RightNav'

const StyledBurger = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;

  @media (min-width: 350px) {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
  }

  div {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
    background-color: ${({ open }) => (open ? '#ccc' : '#333')};
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform-origin: 1px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)')};
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'translateX(100%)' : 'translateX(0)')};
      opacity: ${({ open }) => (open ? 0 : 1)};
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'rotate(-45deg)' : 'rotate(0)')};
    }
  }
`

const Burger = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <StyledBurger open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <div />
        <div />
        <div />
      </StyledBurger>
      <RightNav open={open} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Burger
```

This it the RightNav.jsx file menu imported into the Burger.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Ul = styled.ul`
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;

  li {
    padding: 18px 10px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: #0d2538;
    position: fixed;
    transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(100%)')};
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 3.5rem;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

    li {
      color: #fff;
    }
  }   

`

const RightNav = ({ open }) => {
  return (
    <Ul open={open}>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Sign In</li>
      <li>Sign Up</li>
    </Ul>
  )
}

export default RightNav
```

And this my attempt in the RightNav.jsx file to make it mobile-first, the original code is in comment block:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Ul = styled.ul`
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: #0d2538;
    position: fixed;
    transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(100%)')};
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 3.5rem;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

    li {
      color: #fff;
    }

  @media (min-width: 350px) {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;

  li {
    padding: 18px 10px;
  }
  }  

`

const RightNav = ({ open }) => {
  return (
    <Ul open={open}>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Sign In</li>
      <li>Sign Up</li>
    </Ul>
  )
}

export default RightNav
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies here in the media query in your `min-width` sample:

```
@media (min-width: 350px) {
    ...
    display: none;
}
```

You never set it to a visible display mode after that line of CSS

If you want to hide it on desktop, you'll want to increase the `min-width` value up to `768px` or somewhere in that ballpark. As it is now, you'll only see the menu when the screen size is less than `350px`

Comment: If it's the Burger.jsx, yes the setting for the desktop with min-width is set to display:none, but the default setting is set to to display: flex for the mobile. 
Or do I need it to be set to display:block or display:flex somewhere else too? As its now, with my altered code, the menu is not visible at all on both deskop and mobile.

Comment: The issue is that you're setting to `display: flex;` as default, then immediately changing it to `display: none` when the device is at least 350px wide. If the screen is less than 350px, you'll see that it is `display: flex;`

Comment: Thanks, I changed the min-width_460px, so at least the Burger.jsx is togabled on the mobile, and the mobile settings in RightNav.jsx for the ul and li kicks in, and the flex-flow: column nowrap; is set properly, but its not visible at all above the 460px.
But in the property inspector, when the screen is wider then 460px, I do see that it shows flex-flow: row nowrap but its still not vissible??

Comment: The value of `flex-flow` will stay the same regardless of the display mode the element currently has and doesn't affect it.So if you set it to `display: block` or `display: none`, etc., `flex-flow` will remain unchanged. Check the `display` property to see if it's changing at the right screen width. That's the important one to look at here.

Comment: Yes, it does change from flex-flow: column nowrap to to flex-flow: row nowrap at the set breakpoint of min-with:460px

Comment: The display mode is still `none` though. You need to have `display: flex` and `flex-flow` set for both to apply. If display is `none`, your browser will just ignore the `flex-flow` property.

Comment: But the display for the menu itself in RightNav.jsx (not the Burger.jsx) is set to display:flex as default for the mobile settings, I thought that setting would be inherited in the docoument for the same element coming afterwards.
But I did try to put display:flex on the desktop too, just to try it out, but the menu is still not vissible.

Comment: The default value you are setting it to is `flex` but then you change the display mode to `none` at `350px` in the sample you provided. It will no longer be visible again until you change it back to `display-flex` The reason it applies to everything after that is that you have the media query resetting the value after you set the default. Take the `display: none` out of your media query and you should see it working.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in the code for RightNav.jsx that I set anything to display:none. The display:none is only in the Burger.jsx file to hide the burger divs on desktop.
Could we take this to the chat instead? I should edit my posting to give proper name to my RightNav.jsx as I don't mention it in my posting.